# Finding Z transform of a signal: Intermediate steps

Tags: z-transform

> Find the Z transform of
>
> $y(n)=x(n+2)u(n)$

I have solved the problem. I have doubt whether it is correct or not. It would be very helpful if someone could check whether the steps that I have done are correct or not. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: It seems OK to me. Good job!